# JavaScript return text + playsound

Tags: javascript, html, playsound

So i have a little app based on game (rock paper scissors) but i want to return the text with the winner and a sound effect...
So i have 2 little mp3 files applause.mp3 and fail.mp3
How can i make to return the text and to play the file :( ? i tryed few things but it tells me "undefined" or other errors... :( or maybe it returns me the text buy i couldnt hear the sound..

```
var compare = function(choice1) {
    var winSound = document.getElementById('./sounds/Applause.mp3');  
    var lostSound = document.getElementById('./sounds/Fail.mp3');
    var computerChoice = Math.random();
    if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
        computerChoice = "rock";
    } else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
        computerChoice = "paper";
    } else {
        computerChoice = "scissors";
    }
    if (choice1 === computerChoice) {
        return('The result is a tie!');
      }
    else if (choice1 === 'rock') {
        if (computerChoice === 'scissors') {
           result = 'You are the winner.' + winSound.play();
        } else {
            return 'Computer is the winner.';
        }
    }
    else if (choice1 === 'paper') {
        if (computerChoice === 'rock') {
            return 'You are the winner.';
        } else {
            return 'Computer is the winner.';
        }
    }
    else {
        if (computerChoice === 'rock') {
            return 'You are the winner.';
        } else {
            return 'Computer is the winner.';
        }
    }
};

var game = function(choice1) {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = compare(choice1);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create an audio object:

```
var audio = new Audio();
```

Then assign the src to the sound you want to play in your callback, and play:

```
audio.src = './sounds/Applause.mp3';
audio.load();
audio.play();

return(text);
```

You may want to cache the sounds beforehand so that there is no delay.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to return the sound together with the text. So you can replace this line

```
       result = 'You are the winner.' + winSound.play();
```

with:

```
       winSound.play();
       result = 'You are the winner.';
```

Also, it does not look like you are loading the audio correctly. You probably wanted to put something like `<audio id="win-sound" src="./sounds/Applause.mp3"></audio>` in your HTML and then use `document.getElementById('win-sound')` (see http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp).

Answer (score 0):

winSound.play() does not return a String, but has the side effect of playing the sound. Moreover, you assign the result to a variable instead of returning it. So instead of

```
result = 'You are the winner.' + winSound.play();
```

write:

```
winSound.play();
return 'You are the winner.';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either create the `<audio>` tag as *abhitalks* recommended, or add one to html source:

HTML

```html
<audio id="player"></audio>
```

Javascript

```js
var winSound = './sounds/Applause.mp3';
var lostSound = './sounds/Fail.mp3';
var player = document.getElementById('player'); //audio element
if (result == 'You are the winner.') {
    player.src = winSound;
} else if (result == 'Computer is the winner.') {
    player.src = lostSound;
} else {
    player.src = '';
}
player.load();
player.play();
```

JSFiddle: [full code](http://jsfiddle.net/zA8jC/5/) / [result page](http://jsfiddle.net/zA8jC/5/show)